# Is everything ok (using Present Perfect in the peculiar context)?

Tags: present-perfect

I have a dialogue between two people on translating. I've made up my mind to use Present Perfect (`"I've forgotten"`) but the key says forget. I think that I am right for one simple reason: we have past event, the result having impact on the current situation (speaker hasn't money to buy what they were going to buy); it's some kind of news.

> A: Oh, I've forgotten the money at home.
>
> B: Don't worry. I'll lend you it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88644/discussion-on-question-by-anthony-voronkov-is-everything-ok-using-present-perfe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I've forgotten" is just fine. Probably more common in British English, but certainly not out of place in the States. "I forgot the money" is more direct and more common, but in an extremely formal setting, "I've forgotten" lends a nice tone to the sentence.